# Can I do this better using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<byte[]> data = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(Filename)).ConvertAll<byte[]>(delegate(string value)
    {
        return new List<string>(value.Split('.')).ConvertAll<byte>(delegate(string byteVal)
        {
            return Convert.ToByte(byteVal);
        }).ToArray();
    });
```

Comment: better how? faster? bigger? more readable?

Comment: you should describe your issues with the current code, not just paste your code in the hope that someone will take the time to understand it and guess what you want out of it.

Comment: Kobi: you forgot stronger, harder (see http://www.dothedaft.com/idaft/)

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods are often more succinct than the equivalent LINQ:

```
File.ReadAllLines(Filename).Select(
    line => line.Split('.').Select(ch => Convert.ToByte(ch)).ToArray()
    ).ToArray();
```

In LINQ, this would be:

```
(from line in File.ReadAllLines(Filename)
 select (
     from ch in line.Split('.')
     select Convert.ToByte(ch)
     ).ToArray()
).ToArray()
```

I don't have VS in front of me, so I hope this isn't too far off the mark. Both versions require VS9 (2008) of course.

Comment: `The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`. This works better: `.Select(token => Convert.ToByte(token))`, but is not different enough from your answer to justify another answer :P

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would typically consume the input a line at a time (to allow large files to be processed):

```
static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string path) {
    using (var file = File.OpenText(path)) {
        string line;
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```

and then use:

```
var qry =  from line in ReadLines(Filename)
           select Array.ConvertAll<string,byte>(line.Split('.'), Convert.ToByte);
```

If you **need** a list (rather than a sequence);

```
var list = qry.ToList();
```